# Getting Azure AD auth token from ADF to call RBAC based API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

In ADF, I am trying to call token endpoint to get access token to call an api that is protected by RBAC.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf6Tn.png)

This is how body of first web activity looks like:

```
@concat(concat('tenant=tenantid&client_id=',variables('clientid'),'&client_secret='),variables('clientsecret'),'&user-email=useremail&user-password=pwd','&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default')
```

I am getting the token as a response to this but when I use it to call my API, I get 401 Unauthorized error.

I am able to do the same thing successfully in Postman where I use Postman's "Get New Access Token" feature and I am able to get a token that works on the API from postman.

Comment: can you please try below expression in your body?


@concat('client_id=',variables('clientid'),'&client_secret=',variables('clientsecret'),'&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials')

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below expression in your HTTP body?

```
@concat('client_id=',variables('clientid'),'&client_secret=',variables('clientsecret'),'&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?